# How to launch a URL when an email arrives on Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to launch a URL when an email arrives in Outlook.
The URL is:

> `xyz.host/shared/pdf/DisplayPdf.php?Reservation="6diggitNumber"&ForcePrint=true"`

Is there a possibility to call the URL on mail arrive with the contained 6 Digit Number in the Mail??

```
Sub LaunchURL(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" & " " & Item.Body)
End Sub
```

wont work for me

Comment: Are you running this code off an incoming rule in outlook?  Have you tried the VBA create an IE object and .navigate=url method?  There will be plenty on using Internet Explorer with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just need to change your string concatenation slightly:

```
Sub LaunchURL(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE ""xyz.host/shared/pdf/DisplayPdf.php?Reservation=""" & Item.Body & """&ForcePrint=true"
End Sub
```

When you `Shell` Internet Explorer, you can pass the URL as an argument. you just need to build the string for the URL and pass that as the argument as in the example above.

I've assumed based on your example that you want speech marks `"` around the reservation number in the email body, if not (which I suggest may be the case as you're using the [php](/questions/tagged/php) $_GET method) then remove them - which would look like this:

```
Sub LaunchURL(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE ""xyz.host/shared/pdf/DisplayPdf.php?Reservation=" & Item.Body & "&ForcePrint=true"
End Sub
```